# PHP: How to share data between threads on different servers?

Tags: php, ajax, apache

PHP: How to share data between threads on different servers?

Suppose server has opened separate threads for each connection.

I want to share the data without using database.

Lets say an example:

```
User1-->Logged in on server1-> Playing a game with x points(server is getting score by AJAX).
User2-->Logged in on server2-> Playing same game with y points(server is getting score by AJAX).
```

Now i want to make a list of all logged in user with current score(point) of game.
How can i do that without using database.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a database for this? Having a centralized location to store this data seems like the logical thing to do here.

Comment: gaming sort of applications are not persistent in nature.Some temporary storage makes more sense i guess.

Comment: also PHP PDO overhead is very high for real time app.

Comment: If you only update this when a player starts playing, it would not be such a huge overhead. A database server can take a large amount of queries. There are different types of databases for different kinds of operations. The point here is simply to have a single reference point. It does not mean you should be going with MySQL.

Comment: @Louis, Thanks.. centralized data storage makes sense. i was worried about performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a shared [memcached](http://www.memcached.org/) server and store the data there.

Memcache will act like you would do with a database but much faster, which might be the reason you don't want to use a database here.

Comment: Memcached used like this could be considered to be a non-persistent database.

Comment: I totally agree, we still don't know the reason of the *no database* constraint.

Comment: A non-persistent database without much in the way of indexes.  A real DB would be better for searching by score, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variables every minute with a a script and a CRON job.

Comment: Except that PHP objects get torn down after each request.  There'd be no variables to grab with a cron job.

Comment: from server1, foreach user: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://server2.com/set_points.php?uid={$user['id']}&points={$user['points']}"); curl_exec(); set_points.php saves the variables somewhere, and another script called by ajax will retrieve them.

Comment: There is no "foreach user".  Each session is independent; without a data store of some kind, one session wouldn't even know the others exist.

Comment: also you can keep track of the state, and instead of cron job, every time somebody changes the score will sene notification to other server.

Comment: He did not say no files, for example xml... How he passes the data is not a problem I think.

Comment: I'd thwack anyone who avoids a database because it's "too slow" and then goes and puts stuff in XML.  And yes, how he passes the data is *the entire problem*.  You're saying "pass the variables every minute", but you can't even *get* them outside of the request -- they don't even exist then.  Only the session files remain, and they're not exactly made for quick searching.

Comment: Sure, I also would go for a database approach, but if he cannot there are other (worse) solutions. I am not claiming that this is the best approach, but just going around the problem.